# Is it a way to store only date, no time in CloudKit?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I do not want to store time in `CloudKit`, any way to avoid it? The problem that I get date from `UIDatePicker`, and even dow I set only date (`dp.datePickerMode = .Date`) redundant time info will be stored in `CloudKit` too. Red marked number was not set via date picker.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSDate` has no concept of minutes, hours, seconds, day, months, years. `NSDate` is purely a reference to a single point in time.

It is only when you display a date into a readable format (like a string) that you see anything like Years, Months, Days, Hours, etc...

That is a product of the fact that an NSDate gets **rendered** into a human readable string for debugging.

If you don't want to show the date then don't show the date. The fact is though, someone's date of birth does actually contain hours, minutes and seconds it's just by convention that we decide to truncate it down to days only.

Just use the `NSDate` and when you display it just only display the date part.

BTW

When you don't show the time in a `UIDatePicker` then the current time will be used.

Comment: understand, if I want to nullify, the when I am reading date picker, I have to remove time values

Comment: You can't "remove the time values". You could set them all to 0 but then you will still have a time part of the NSDate it will just be 00:00:00.000 which is still a time. Just leave the time parts alone. Ignore them. They're not taking up any space.

Comment: the real problem is not displaying it, I am not displaying time components, but the challenge was to **compare**, .. so if all date time is truncated then I can compare wether the selected date in picker exist in database or not

Comment: @János OK, if you want to see if two dates are "the same day" for instance then there is a function (I believe on NSCalendar) or you can use my Cocoapod... http://www.oliverfoggin.com/nsdate-isequaltodatetounitgranularity/

Comment: but why do I need any function or `NSCalendar` magic for it? I just truncate all date times, and compare them `"dateOfBirth = %@", obj`

Comment: @János because time and dates are hard. "Truncating times" still doesn't really mean anything. It's much better to use a function that can properly check if two dates are the same month, year, day, hour, minute, etc...

Comment: @János you still have to remember that on its own `NSDate` doesn't have any idea what day, hour, etc.. it is. It's only when it is put into a calendar that it understands. A point in time has no such thing as a day. It's only the gregorian calendar that determines what day it is. There are also multiple calendars available within iOS so for instance you function for "truncating the times" might work in the UK but not in China. It's much safer to use a function like this which forces you to specify which calendar you are working with. Even if it's just the "current calendar".

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of reasons to only store a date. Apple does not provide one. So use an ISO - like format, 2014/06/22 in a string.

Storing a time and date when you only have a date, (like a birthday or calendar day) is usually not a good practice. One huge pitfall of storing an NSDate when you only want a day is that you will usually get the displayed date changing depending on what time zone you show it from. People's birthdays don't change based on timezone.

Comment: Yes, but people's dates of birth **DO** change depending on timezone. If you are born in the UK on 31st December 2014 at 10pm then in Australia it is about 8am on 1st January 2015.